# Passing the value of textbox as form id

Tags: grails, grails-controller, grails-2.4, grails-2.5

Trying to pass the value entered in a textbox by a user as the id of the form. Code snippet below. This always passes params.id = "index" in my controller. If i hardcode form id="someText" it passes params.id = "someText" to controller. Due to certain constraints i have to use  button element instead of g:actionsubmit.

```
<g:form controller="search" action="index" id=${searchText} method="post">
    <div>
        <g:textField name="searchText"></g:textField>       
         <button type="submit" class="btn">
            <i class="icon-search"></i>
         </button>
    </div>
</g:form>
```

Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

```
<g:form controller="search" action="index" method="post">
    <div>
        <g:textField name="id"></g:textField>       
        <button type="submit" class="btn">
            <i class="icon-search"></i>
        </button>
    </div>
</g:form>
```

Comment: I had tried this before posting the question. params.id = 'index' is passed when name of textfied is 'id'